# If someone is seen online does that mean they have opened our conversation or any conversation on whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When you open a conversation on whatsapp and the contact is seen as online have they opened your conversation or just any conversation?

Answer (score 2):

You can read from the WhatsApp FAQ:

> ## [What does "last seen at..." and "online" mean exactly?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/20971848)
>
> "online" means that contact has WhatsApp open and is connected to the internet. However, it does not necessarily mean they have read your chat.

That clearly stats that a contact with "online" status just needs to have the app opened within an active Internet connection.